# How to display non-zoomable webpage at Android (Nexus 7)

Tags: android, html, mobile-website, nexus-7, android-resolution

Client reports problem with my webpage on Nexus 7. Nexus have 1280x800 native resolution and I need display my webpage on this device (and other androids) non-zoomable, so in 1280x800resolution.

Before problem report, I had this setting for viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and from log I know that JS detected his resolution as 750x534 and my HTC EVO (native res. 960x540) had 640x308.

Than I changed viewport to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
```

source
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity

and My HTC EVO now display page in 960x462 (ok nonzoom) but Nexus still display this page in 962x442

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, workd for me

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, height=device-height">
```